# Htaccess mod_rewrite issue - Regex not working correct

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

just experiencing a huge (for me, the regex newb) problem:

We have a multiste with nested folders, and one line in the htaccess fails in converting to the correct urls:

> RewriteRule  ^(.+)?/(wp-.*) /$2 [L]

The line should break out everything before the first wp-, and append the rest of the string to the root url. f.e:

> /kitchen/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.css

should become

> /wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.css

but with the above Regex converts to

> wp-mediaelement.css

On Urls where there is only one wp-, the thing works. So the error is that apache takes the last occurence of wp- instead of the first.

Long talking:
How can i adjust the above regex to work as expected?

Greets to all!

Edit: Beforte the first wp- can be anything. not only one path. It could also be

```
/lalelu/loleli/wp-includes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(wp-.*) /$2 [L]
```

should do the trick

edit: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be is a nice tool to quickly debug your rewrite rules

Comment: Thx Taos..;) Wondering what`s the difference to the original? Andy why it`s now ignoring all other wp- ?

Comment: glad we could help :) the ? (non greedy) has to directly follow * or +